# How do I create a working filter to block sites, etc with NoRoot Firewall?

Tags: applications, browser, vpn, firefox-for-android, content-filter

NRF seems fine for blocking applications' use of data, but not blocking sites or other communication with them on a case-by-case basis; it's an all-or-nothing proposition.

I've followed guides on how to do it, entered pre-filters and in-app filters, but in setting Firefox to use them, I get status bar notifications that Firefox wants to access the internet and an unending stream of Pending Access-es -- for sites that don't have filters set for them -- that are impossible to keep up with. It won't do so at all before timing out, unless I globally Allow or Deny.

I read on Lifehacker that NRF has issues on 4G, which my phone is, but I'm strictly on wi-fi, so should be a moot issue, yeah?

I've looked at the builder's site, norootfirewall.weebly.com, but it has no additional info or contact, and Firefox doesn't seem to have a filter add-on that actually works on mobile (I use BlockSite on desktop), so here I am. Help!?

[image: NRF application settings][image: Firefox filters][image: visitijg timeanddate.com, an un-blocked site][image: all or nothijg][image: sites pending access list]
[image: global filters]